# Receiving JSON Response

Tags: java, json, tomcat, jersey

I am trying to receive a JSON response with Jersey but it is always sending null.  Here is my service code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
        MediaType.TEXT_XML })
@Path("/songs/")
public Room AddSong(@PathParam("json") String Info) {
    Song newSong = new newSong();
    newSong.addSong(Info);
    return newSong;
}
```

In this case, "Info" is always null.  I receive a 200 response from the server so I know the JSON is being sent.  The only other thing im not sure is, should I sent JSON in UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use @PathParam correctly. You need to specify {json} in your url. Look at the [example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-pathparam-example/)

UPD: It's just occurred to me, you in your case you don't need to use @PathParam at all. Just put it away and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the @PathParam as the JSON contents should be in the POST body.  You have declared the return type to be *Room*, but are you not trying to return type *Song*?  Assuming this is a simple JSON wrapped string, the contents are in the POST body, and you want *Song* returned in the 200 OK then you can try this:

```
@POST
Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML })
@Path("/songs/")
public Song AddSong(String Info) {
    Song newSong = new newSong();
    newSong.addSong(Info);
    return newSong;
}
```

Optionally, if you want to use a JSON representation of *Song* in the API, you can replace *String Info* with *Song newSong* and then specific *Song* in the POST body.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Path parameters take the incoming URL and match parts of the path as a parameter. By including {name} in a @Path annotation, the resource
>   can later access the matching part of the URI to a path parameter with
>   the corresponding "name". Path parameters make parts of the request
>   URL as parameters which can be useful in embedding request parameter
>   information to a simple URL.***

```
@Path("/books/{bookid}")
public class BookResource {
    @GET
    public Response invokeWithBookId(@PathParam("bookid") String bookId) {
        /* get the info for bookId */
        return Response.ok(/* some entity here */).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{language}")
    public Response invokeWithBookIdAndLanguage(@PathParam("bookid") String bookId, @PathParam("language") String language) {
        /* get the info for bookId */
        return Response.ok(/* some entity here */).build();
    }
}
```

***In your rest code argument `Info` takes value from `@Path("/songs/{json}")` but you have specify `@Path("/songs/")` so `json` will always be `null`***

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
        MediaType.TEXT_XML })
@Path("/songs/")
public Room AddSong(@PathParam("json") String Info) {
    Song newSong = new newSong();
    newSong.addSong(Info);
    return newSong;
}
```

You do like this and then everything will be fine :

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
            MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    @Path("/songs/{json}")
    public Room AddSong(@PathParam("json") String Info) {
        Song newSong = new newSong();
        newSong.addSong(Info);
        return newSong;
    }
```

For more info refer [JAX-RS Parameters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WINK/JAX-RS+Parameters)